# Call array on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following jquery array, that takes the values from two columns from my table and show's their value:

```js
var myCollection = [];
$('#MainContent_gvKarakteristike tbody').find('tr:gt(0)').each(function() {
  var row = this;
  var myObj = {

    label: valuefromType($(row).find($(row).find('td:eq(1)').children())),
    opis: valuefromType($(row).find($(row).find('td:eq(2)').children()))
  };
  myCollection[myCollection.length] = myObj;
});

function valuefromType(control) {
  var type = $(control).prop('nodeName').toLowerCase();
  switch (type) {
    case "input":
      return $(control).val();
      break;
    case "span":
      return $(control).text();
      break;
    case "select":
      return $(control).val();
      break;

  }
}
```

Name of the first column is 'label' and name of the second is 'opis'
Result:

```
myCollection
(6) […]
​
0: Object { label: "1", opis: "Test1" }
​
1: Object { label: "2", opis: "Test2" }
​
2: Object { label: "3", opis: "Test3" }
​
3: Object { label: "5", opis: "1" }
​
4: Object { label: "9", opis: "Test5" }
​
5: Object { label: "15", opis: "Test6" }
​
length: 6
```

The problem I have is that this code works only on page reload, and I need it to work on button click.

Button :

```
<button id="myButton"  type="button">Save</button>
```

I have tried many things and myCollection array is always undefined.

Example:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#myButton').click(function() {
    var myCollection = [];
    $('#MainContent_gvKarakteristike tbody').find('tr:gt(0)').each(function() {
      var row = this;
      var myObj = {

        label: valuefromType($(row).find($(row).find('td:eq(1)').children())),
        opis: valuefromType($(row).find($(row).find('td:eq(2)').children()))
      };
      myCollection[myCollection.length] = myObj;
    });

    function valuefromType(control) {
      var type = $(control).prop('nodeName').toLowerCase();
      switch (type) {
        case "input":
          return $(control).val();
          break;
        case "span":
          return $(control).text();
          break;
        case "select":
          return $(control).val();
          break;


      }
    }
  });
});
```

Can someone help me get values from the array with the #myButton click ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: is the #myButton added dynamically

Comment: Nope, I just added the html my self.

Comment: The the below answer and comment plz

Comment: Where specifically do you see `myCollection` as `undefined`?

Comment: I type in the console myCollection to see if the values will appear like they appear on the page load correctly.

Comment: @freej17: Well, it's only defined within the scope of this click handler function.  So the debugger won't be able to see it unless you're paused on a breakpoint in that scope.  But you're also only using it within the scope of this click handler function, so this sounds like it's not really a problem but just a misunderstanding while debugging.

Comment: If I understand correctly array is correctly populated with values but it just is not shown when I check it trough the console ?

Comment: can you fiddle it: https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @freej17: That sounds like what's happening, yes.  After you populate the array, try `console.log(myCollection)` and see what's there.  (Currently you don't do anything at all with the array, you just populate it and then let it fall out of scope.)

Comment: Thanks David, this works perfectly !!! :) 
Everything is ok now.